# After leaving my PC alone for as little as 5 minutes, I come back to an error where the enter key seems to be constantly pressed

Tags: keyboard, troubleshooting, skype

This is a bit of a strange question, so I will try and give as much information as I can.

Let me start by saying that the enter key on my keyboard is absolutely fine, physically. I am writing this post using the enter key (or lack there of).

However, sometimes, if I leave my computer alone for as few as 5 minutes I will come back to the enter key acting like it is constantly being pressed. Meaning if I try to type in Skype, my message would show up as hundreds of one letter messages as opposed to one paragraph of text.

One thing I have noticed though, is that most of the time I have found out this error, it is me typing a message on Skype.

Another problem I have found when using the video feature of Skype is that my mouse and keyboard both freeze simultaneously in place for 5-10 seconds, then come back and work as normal until it freezes again (this can be 5 seconds after, or 10 minutes later, it really is random).

I have got a Razer Blackwidow 2014 keyboard, and a Razer Naga Hex mouse, with the Razer Synapse 2.0 software, which is fully updated and configured correctly.

I know there is a lack of information here, but if there is anymore information I can give you I will try my best. Troubleshooting the problem has become quite a chore, as making one change (uninstalling Skype for example) may not give immediate results, and may take hours before I found out what is causing this problem.

I thank you in advance for any responses to a very annoying issue.

Comment: Does it only happen in skype? And not in... say... notepad? Or does it happen in any software? And does a reboot fix the issue even if just temporarily?

Comment: A thorough virus scan might be in order... key-presses can be generated programmatically.

Comment: It occurs in all programs, a reboot does fix the problem. Until it happens again. While using the system, it doesn't seem to have any problems. It only happens when I leave it alone for a while.

Comment: I will get a full virus scan running now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Still no luck, however, I have now found that if I am using a game, in this case WoW, it does not affect the game at all. I can type to friends and in chat completely fine, but if I go to the desktop and try to use anything (even explorer, which makes opening applications hard to test), I get a constant enter key spam which I cannot stop.